# vb6.0 to vb.net Sharp Grid to dataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, vb6-migration

I have to convert the code from vb6.0 to vs2010. In Vb6 sharp grid has been used but when i am converting it into vs2010, i am getting the problem in following lines

productGrid is Sharp Grid of vb6. there are 13 columns in productGrid and 1st column is checkbox type.

```
       'Needed to get the dropdown list to refresh properly
        lRow = ProductGrid.Row
        lTopRow = ProductGrid.TopRow
        ProductGrid.Row = IIf(lRow = 1, 2, lRow - 1)
        ProductGrid.Row = lRow
        ProductGrid.TopRow = lTopRow
```

Comment: Where is exactly the problem? (and what type of problem, an error?) Why in the comment says dropdown? Is one of the columns a dropdown/combobox?

Comment: yes one column is dropdown. I am not able to convert this code in vb.net, Not getting the exactly meaning of these lines, what this code is doing

Comment: This specific code seems to be pointless. It TRIES to redefine the rows (the given one and the top one) by relying on IIF (which, btw, is supported by VB.NET) but what it does is nothing: assigns to lRow = ProductGrid.Row at the start and afterwards makes ProductGrid.Row = lRow (= back to the previous state), same thing for TopRow. This code does not produce any change. The only option of this code to do something would be removing the last two lines.

Comment: means during conversion if i will not add this code then it does not effect the code.

Comment: I guess that this was implicit in my previous comment.